# Pandas data frame: resample with linear interpolation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I am trying to get a fairly basic resampling method to work with a pandas data frame. My data  frame df is indexed by datetime entries and contains prices

```
                               price
datetime                            
2000-08-16 09:29:55.755000  7.302786
2000-08-16 09:30:10.642000  7.304059
2000-08-16 09:30:26.598000  7.304435
2000-08-16 09:30:41.372000  7.304314
2000-08-16 09:30:56.718000  7.304334
```

I would like to downsample this to 5min. Using

```
df.resample(rule='5Min',how='last',closed='left')
```

takes the closest point to the left in my data of a multiple of 5min; similarly

```
df.resample(rule='5Min',how='first',closed='left')
```

takes the closes point to the right.
However, I would like to take the linear interpolation between the point to the left and right instead, e.g. if my df contains the two consecutive entries

```
time t1, price p1
time t2, price p2
```

and

```
t1<t<t2 where t is a multiple of 5min
```

then the resampled dataframe should have the entry

```
time t, price p1+(t-t1)/(t2-t1)*(p2-p1)
```

Comment: There was a [similar question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25234941/478288), but that didn't get a good answer though.

Comment: Meanwhile that other question got some more good answers, e.g. [this one with .interpolate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39730730/1389680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try creating two separate dataframes, `reset_index` them (so they have the same numerical index), `fillna` on them, and then just do the math on df1 and df2. e.g:

```
df1 = df.resample(rule='5Min',how='last',closed='left').reset_index().fillna(method='ffill')
df2 = df.resample(rule='5Min',how='first',closed='left').reset_index().fillna(method='ffill')

dt = df1.datetime - df2.datetime
px_fld = df1.price + ...
```

something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, dt = df1.datetime - df2.datetime is then not defined.

Comment: what do you mean by that? it's defined at `dt = df1.datetime - df2.datetime`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry what i meant is that df1.datetime gives an error since we used    reset_index. However, just using     df1['index'] instead works then exactly as you said. Many thanks!

Comment: ah, i see. i was thinking that because the original df had 'datetime' as the index name that it would carry over. sorry about that, but glad you figured it out.

Comment: I need to do this also but since the answer is not complete I am having trouble. My attempt goes like this `val = df1.value + (df0.timestamp - df1.timestamp) / (df2.timestamp - df1.timestamp) * (df2.value - df1.value)`. I can't see a use for df1.datetime - df2.datetime.