# Fill in time data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is every 15 seconds. But, there are some values that are missing.  These are not tagged with NaN, but simply are not present.  How can I fill in those values?
I have tried to resample, but that also shifts my original data.  So, why doesn't this work:

```
a=pd.Series([1.,3.,4.,3.,5.],['2016-05-25 00:00:35','2016-05-25 00:00:50','2016-05-25 00:01:05','2016-05-25 00:01:35','2016-05-25 00:02:05'])                                   
a.index=pd.to_datetime(a.index)
a.resample('15S').mean()

In [368]: a
Out[368]: 
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.0
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.0
dtype: float64
```

It shows me this:

```
2016-05-25 00:00:30    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:45    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:00    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:15    NaN
2016-05-25 00:01:30    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:45    NaN
2016-05-25 00:02:00    5.0
Freq: 15S, dtype: float64
```

So, I no longer have a value at 00:35 or 00:50.
For my original larger data set, I also end up seeing many NaN value in large groups at the end of the resampled data.
What I would like to do resample my 15s data, to 15s, so whenever there is no data present for a particular time it should use the mean of the values around it to fill it in.  Is there a way to do that?
Also, why does the time basis change when I resample?  My original data starts at 00:00:35 and after resampling it starts at 00:30?  It seems like it got shifted by 5 seconds.
In my example data, all it should have done is created an additional data entry at 00:01:50.

---

**Edit**

I realized that my data is slightly more complex then I had thought.  The 'base' actually changes part way through it.  If I use the solution below, then it works for part of the data, but then the values stop changing.  For example:

```
a = pd.Series([1.,3.,4.,3.,5.,6.,7.,8.], ['2016-05-25 00:00:35','2016-05-25 00:00:50','2016-05-25 00:01:05','2016-05-25 00:01:35','2016-05-25 00:02:05','2016-05-25 00:03:00','2016-05-25 00:04:00','2016-05-25 00:06:00'])                                   

In [79]: a
Out[79]: 
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.0
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.0
2016-05-25 00:03:00    6.0
2016-05-25 00:04:00    7.0
2016-05-25 00:06:00    8.0
dtype: float64

In [80]: a.index = pd.to_datetime(a.index)

In [81]: a.resample('15S', base=5).interpolate()
Out[81]: 
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:20    3.5
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:50    4.0
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.0
2016-05-25 00:02:20    5.0
2016-05-25 00:02:35    5.0
2016-05-25 00:02:50    5.0
2016-05-25 00:03:05    5.0
2016-05-25 00:03:20    5.0
2016-05-25 00:03:35    5.0
2016-05-25 00:03:50    5.0
2016-05-25 00:04:05    5.0
2016-05-25 00:04:20    5.0
2016-05-25 00:04:35    5.0
2016-05-25 00:04:50    5.0
2016-05-25 00:05:05    5.0
2016-05-25 00:05:20    5.0
2016-05-25 00:05:35    5.0
2016-05-25 00:05:50    5.0
Freq: 15S, dtype: float64
```

As you can see it stops interpolating after 2:05, and seems to ignore the data at 3:00,4:00 and 5:00.

Comment: You should use the `base` argument of `resample`.

Comment: Can one of you help explain "base"?  What are the units?  I see that using base=5 does the job, but i've read the resample docs, and it really is not clear why 5 is correct and not 35 for example? As well as loffset?

Comment: This looks similar to what I have been trying to do.  But is complex and inefficient for large data:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234941/python-regularise-irregular-time-series-with-linear-interpolation

Comment: But then it's not clear what you want. Can you show your desired output is with the new example? Ideally you would ask a new question, as this one has become too confused. You should re-accept Alberto'/s answer, and ask a new question with your new example and your desired output.

Comment: I would like to return an exact value when the input time matches the output time, and an interpolated value when the output time is between two input times.  So 2:05 should be 5.0 but 2:20 should be about 5.25.  and 2:35 should be about 5.5 (these are just approx, not the exact answer).

Comment: To put it another way, I have somewhat irregular data.  I want Pandas to give me a "best guess" every 15 second.  Clearly, the best answer is the exact one, when the times match up.  Otherwise, I want to use interpolate to that time stamp for a best guess (although, there are other reasonable algorithms that could be used as well)

Comment: So you want your final timestamps to be regular, i.e. every 15 seconds?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  With a local interpolation, when necessary, and the exact point, when it is available.

Comment: Weird, `a.resample('15S', base=5).interpolate()` works for me. Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Note that the code above does the resampling first, then the interpolation, which means that the value at `2:50` will be exactly the original value at `3:00`. If that's not what you want, then you will probably have to upsample to 5-seconds frequency first, interpolate, then downsample back to 15-seconds. Again, I recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: @IanS I'm using 0.18.1 and I get the results shown above.  Which version are you using, and what results do you get?

Comment: Good point, I use version 0.18.0, and with 0.18.1 I see the same result as you. You should report a bug here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues (I don't think it has been reported before).

Comment: @IanS Done:  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/14297

Answer (score 5):

Both @IanS and @piRSquared address the shifting of the base. As for filling `NaN`s: pandas has methods for forward-filling (`.ffill()`/`.pad()`) and backward-filling (`.bfill()`/`.backfill()`), but not for taking the mean. A quick way of doing it is by taking the mean manually:

```
b = a.resample('15S', base=5)
(b.ffill() + b.bfill()) / 2
```

Output:

```
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:20    3.5
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:50    4.0
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.0
Freq: 15S, dtype: float64
```

EDIT: I stand corrected: there is a built-in method: `.interpolate()`.

```
a.resample('15S', base=5).interpolate()
```

Comment: Good point. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691949/5276797) should work too: `df.fillna(df.mean())`.

Comment: Can one of you help explain "base"? What are the units? I see that using base=5 does the job, but i've read the resample docs, and it really is not clear why 5 is correct and not 35 for example? As well as loffset?

Comment: In this example, `base` is an integer between 0 and 14 that makes the timeseries begin at midnight past `base` seconds. The argument itself is an integer, but the units are implicitly the frequency's unit.

Comment: @Adam (not sure if you'd be notified otherwise)

Comment: @IanS it turns out that this solution only works for part of the data.  So, I expanded the question some.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, the `base` argument works too:

```
a.resample('15S', base=5).mean()
Out[4]: 
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.0
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.0
2016-05-25 00:01:20    NaN
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.0
2016-05-25 00:01:50    NaN
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.0
Freq: 15S, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `loffset` argument

```
a.resample('15S', loffset='5S')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An answer was posted to my [bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/14297) that I wanted to share here for completeness. It is not my post, but does just what I had wanted:

Try this (maybe this is what interpolate should do by default, interpolating before re-sampling?)

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# fit the interpolation in integer ns-space
f = interp1d(a.index.asi8, a.values)

# generating ending bins
dates = a.resample('15s', base=5).first().index

# apply
pd.Series(f(dates.asi8), dates)
Out[122]: 
2016-05-25 00:00:35    1.000000
2016-05-25 00:00:50    3.000000
2016-05-25 00:01:05    4.000000
2016-05-25 00:01:20    3.500000
2016-05-25 00:01:35    3.000000
2016-05-25 00:01:50    4.000000
2016-05-25 00:02:05    5.000000
2016-05-25 00:02:20    5.272727
2016-05-25 00:02:35    5.545455
2016-05-25 00:02:50    5.818182
2016-05-25 00:03:05    6.083333
2016-05-25 00:03:20    6.333333
2016-05-25 00:03:35    6.583333
2016-05-25 00:03:50    6.833333
2016-05-25 00:04:05    7.041667
2016-05-25 00:04:20    7.166667
2016-05-25 00:04:35    7.291667
2016-05-25 00:04:50    7.416667
2016-05-25 00:05:05    7.541667
2016-05-25 00:05:20    7.666667
2016-05-25 00:05:35    7.791667
2016-05-25 00:05:50    7.916667
Freq: 15S, dtype: float64
```