# pandas resample interpolate is producing NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Modified from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730730/125507):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = io.StringIO('''\
Values
1992-08-27 07:46:48,1
1992-08-27 08:00:48,2
1992-08-27 08:33:48,4
1992-08-27 08:43:48,3
1992-08-27 08:48:48,1
1992-08-27 08:51:48,5
1992-08-27 08:53:48,4
1992-08-27 08:56:48,2
1992-08-27 09:03:48,1
''')
s = pd.read_csv(data, squeeze=True)
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)

res = s.resample('4s').interpolate('linear')
print(res)
plt.plot(res, '.-')
plt.plot(s, 'o')
plt.grid(True)
```

It works as expected:

```
1992-08-27 07:46:48    1.000000
1992-08-27 07:46:52    1.004762
1992-08-27 07:46:56    1.009524
1992-08-27 07:47:00    1.014286
1992-08-27 07:47:04    1.019048
1992-08-27 07:47:08    1.023810
1992-08-27 07:47:12    1.028571
....
```

[image: interpolated values]

but if I change the resample to `'5s'`, it produces only NaNs:

```
1992-08-27 07:46:45   NaN
1992-08-27 07:46:50   NaN
1992-08-27 07:46:55   NaN
1992-08-27 07:47:00   NaN
1992-08-27 07:47:05   NaN
1992-08-27 07:47:10   NaN
1992-08-27 07:47:15   NaN
....
```

Why?

Comment: just came across this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66967998/10197418) - it gets even more confusing if `resample` leaves you with *some* data left (not all NaN).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Option 1**
That's because `'4s'` aligns perfectly with your existing index.  When you `resample`, you get representation from your old series and are able to interpolate.  What you want to do is to create an index that is the union of the old index with a new index.  Then interpolate and reindex with a new index.

```
oidx = s.index
nidx = pd.date_range(oidx.min(), oidx.max(), freq='5s')
res = s.reindex(oidx.union(nidx)).interpolate('index').reindex(nidx)
res.plot(style='.-')
s.plot(style='o')
```

[image]

---

**Option 2A**
If you are willing to forgo accuracy, you can `ffill` with a limit of `1`

```
res = s.resample('5s').ffill(limit=1).interpolate()
res.plot(style='.-')
s.plot(style='o')
```

[image]

---

**Option 2B**
Same thing with `bfill`

```
res = s.resample('5s').bfill(limit=1).interpolate()
res.plot(style='.-')
s.plot(style='o')
```

[image]

---

**Option 3**
Intermediate complexity and accuracy

```
nidx = pd.date_range(oidx.min(), oidx.max(), freq='5s')
res = s.reindex(nidx, method='nearest', limit=1).interpolate()
res.plot(style='.-')
s.plot(style='o')
```

[image]

Comment: it really has to be that complicated?  ultimately I want to downsample it again afterward, but I can't just run the downsampling on the original non-uniformly sampled data or it won't count the signal between the samples

Comment: I don't see a way to do this more succinctly with the current api.  I could be wrong, but this is the best I can do.

Comment: @endolith However, I added some options you may like.

Comment: @JamesAdams glad it helped you out

Comment: Wow this was so helpful. Looked for ages for something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add astype() to make it work, otherwise it produced Nan values:

```
oidx = s.index
nidx = pd.date_range(oidx.min(), oidx.max(), freq='2min')
res=s.reindex(oidx.union(nidx)).astype(float).interpolate('index').reindex(nidx)
```