# shift pandas dataframe rows to the nearest timestep

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

### Background

I have a large dataframe consisting of 100's of thousands of values. The head of dataframe looks as below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 1100, 1400, np.nan, 14000],
                   index=pd.to_datetime(["2011-05-25 10:00:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 16:40:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:06:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:10:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:24:00"])

                           0
2011-05-25 10:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 16:40:00   1100.0
2011-05-25 17:06:00   1400.0
2011-05-25 17:10:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:24:00  14000.0
```

### what I want

The values are not always recorded with 6 minute time step. I want to shift the values which are not recorded at 6 minute time step to the nearest 6 minute step. I want the new dataframe to look like below

```py
n_df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 1100, 1400, np.nan, 14000],
                   index=pd.to_datetime(["2011-05-25 10:00:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 16:42:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:06:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:12:00",
                                         "2011-05-25 17:24:00"])
                   )

                           0
2011-05-25 10:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 16:42:00   1100.0
2011-05-25 17:06:00   1400.0
2011-05-25 17:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:24:00  14000.0
```

What is important for me that all the values in n_df should be at 6 minute time step and thus the attribute `n_df.index.freq` must not be `None`.

How can I achieve this.

So far I am doing it using `for` loop by iterating over `df` and finding the nearest 6 minute step and shifting/copying the value to that step, but this is very slow if `df` is larger than 1000.

### what I have tried

```py
    index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="6min")
    pydatetime_index = index.to_pydatetime()
    n_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=index)

    for _idx, i in enumerate(df.index):
        nearest_neighbor = np.abs(pydatetime_index - i.to_pydatetime())
        idx = np.argmin(nearest_neighbor)
        val = df.loc[i]
        n_df.iloc[idx] = val
```

Comment: Instead of argmin, which needs to loop over the whole `index` you can loop over only offsets of -3 min, -2 min ... +2 min, +3 min. That should improve your speed. If you don't mind creating new nan entries at 6 minute intervals you should do reindex or resample like @jazrael's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `nearest` and specify `tolerance` parameter:

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="6min")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

df2 = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                    df, 
                    left_index=True, 
                    right_index=True, 
                    direction='nearest', 
                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('3Min'))
print (df2)
                           0
2011-05-25 10:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:06:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:24:00      NaN
                     ...
2011-05-25 17:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:06:00   1400.0
2011-05-25 17:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:24:00  14000.0

[75 rows x 1 columns]
```

Or similar with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 = df.reindex(index, method='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('3Min'))
print (df2)
                           0
2011-05-25 10:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:06:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:24:00      NaN
                     ...
2011-05-25 17:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:06:00   1400.0
2011-05-25 17:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:24:00  14000.0

[75 rows x 1 columns]
```

Or:

```
df2 = df.resample('6Min').first()
print (df2)
                           0
2011-05-25 10:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:06:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 10:24:00      NaN
                     ...
2011-05-25 17:00:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:06:00   1400.0
2011-05-25 17:12:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:18:00      NaN
2011-05-25 17:24:00  14000.0

[75 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Is there a way to add interpolation option with your answers. For example we know value at 16:40:00 is 1100 and value at 17:06:00 is 1400. Is it possible that we put interpolated value at 16:42?

Comment: @AtherCheema - Really complicated, do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148446/pandas-resample-interpolate-is-producing-nans) ?