# Equal spacing between two row data into data frame for only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have one data frame and with approx 4000 rows and the spacing between the rows are not equal. So, I want to make spacing equally.
for example:

```
len1                            len1
1.133124                        1.0
1.251545                        1.5
1.455714                        2.0
1.641502                        2.5
1.864047                        3.0
2.066187                        3.5
```

Like this way. 
Please help me, I am a beginner.

Comment: What do you mean by "spacing between rows" ?

Comment: Difference between one-row data to another row data

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: The second column as I mention above e.g. 1.0, 1.5

Comment: How do you determine the spacing?

Comment: By the difference between second-row data to first row data. but the difference is not equal that is the problem.

Comment: I suspect you are asking about how to regularize an irregular time series. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234941/python-regularise-irregular-time-series-with-linear-interpolation

Comment: There is no logical function that maps your left column to your right column. You question makes no sense IMO. If you just need the right column, use `np.linspace`.

Comment: No, i do not have time frame data.

Comment: No, this data frame I have but I need the difference between in row data is equal. for example: 1.133124-1.251545 =0.118421

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that there are white spaces in the data? 
example:

```
             len1  
0        1.133124                    
1    1.251545                  
2      1.455714                       
3     1.641502      
4       1.864047  
5    2.066187
```

If this is indeed your question the following would help:

```
df['len1'].str.strip()
```

This strips the white space and would give:

```
         len1  
0    1.133124                    
1    1.251545                  
2    1.455714                       
3    1.641502      
4    1.864047  
5    2.066187
```

Comment: No,  this data frame I have but I need the difference between in row data is equal. for example: 1.133124-1.251545 =0.118421

Comment: Then I don't know what your question is